# Parse server relational query not working

Tags: swift, database, relational-database, parse-server

I have two classes in parse server called `_User` and `Organization`, in `User` i have Relational column `organization` type

```
"organization": {
    "__type": "Relation",
    "className": "Organization"
},
```

Im using swift 3 to query my Users from `Users` class and i want to include (join) all organizations that related to each user, so i have trying with

```
let innerQuery = PFQuery(className: "Organization")
let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
query.whereKey("organization", matchesQuery: innerQuery)
query.findObjectsInBackground {  }
```

but this code give me error

this is the query

```
{
    "limit": "1500",
    "where": {
        "organization": {
            "$inQuery": {
                "className": "Organization"
            }
        }
    },
    "_method": "GET"
}
```

and result.

```
{
    "code": 102,
    "error": "improper usage of $inQuery"
}
```

why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Organization")
    query.whereKey("organization", equalTo: PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName:"_User", objectId:PFUser.currentUser()!))
    query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error)-> Void in
```